# certificate chain is not coming with server certificate

Tags: java, openssl, x509certificate, keystore, jks

The keystore contains **CA**,**Certificate**,and the **private Key**

```
bash:$ keytool -list -keystore my.keystore 
Enter keystore password:  

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 6 entries

xyz-server-ca, Nov 12, 2015, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): F1:94:1E:B3:C1:E7:7E:54:DA:6B:12:35:26:AA:4C:DE:46:D6:45:3F
xyz-key, Nov 12, 2015, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 81:45:05:29:15:26:0C:0E:71:EB:E0:1F:3E:1C:D8:FE:C6:8D:78:69
xyz-root-ca, Nov 12, 2015, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 67:D6:A8:37:AD:16:15:31:6D:55:78:02:F2:FA:AB:7A:2A:75:F0:DF
server, Nov 12, 2015, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 
xyz-root-ca1, Nov 12, 2015, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 67:D6:A8:37:AD:36:15:31:6D:55:78:02:F2:FA:AB:7A:2A:75:F0:DF
server, Nov 12, 2015, trustedCertEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1):
```

When i do to view the certificate chain using openssl, it doesn't return me all the chain, instead of it's just return the server Certificate and one CA file

openssl s_client -host 127.0.0.1 -port 443  -prexit -showcerts

```
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=EU/ST=I/L=Du/O=Inc./OU=Foot/CN=example.com
   i:/C= EU/O=I/OU=Du/CN=Servers CA
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behavior. When making an SSL handshake, server responds with its own SSL certificate and all CA certificates in the chain ***except root certificate***. A reference from [RFC 5246 §7.4.2][1]:

> certificate_list
> This is a sequence (chain) of certificates.  The sender's
> certificate MUST come first in the list.  Each following
> certificate MUST directly certify the one preceding it.  Because
> certificate validation requires that root keys be distributed
> independently, the self-signed certificate that specifies the root
> certificate authority MAY be omitted from the chain, under the
> assumption that the remote end must already possess it in order to
> validate it in any case.

In other words, it is a good practice to NOT send root (which is presented in a self-signed form) certificate during SSL negotiation.
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.2

Comment: I don't believe its expected behavior (if the problem statement/title is accurate: ***"certificate chain is not coming with server certificate"***). A well configured server sends its certificate, and all intermediates required to build a path to a root. Also see the [PKI "which directory" problem](http://www.google.com/search?num=40&q=PKI+"which+directory"+problem).

Comment: As per OP: "it's just return the server Certificate and one CA file", at least one CA cert is shipped, which is  OK for 2-tier PKI.

Comment: How can i get all the certificate chain ?

Comment: SSL server should not respond with a full chain, it should respond with a partial chain which excludes root certificate.